# How can I add an Array to a Plist using PlistBuddy?

Tags: ios, xcode, bash, shell, plist

This question is a Sub-Question/Alternative Way to approach what I am trying to do via this question: [How can I use PListBuddy to copy an entry from one file to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562946/how-can-i-use-plistbuddy-to-copy-an-entry-from-one-file-to-another)

I want to copy an Entry from Plist File A to Plist File B using PlistBuddy through an XCode Build Script, using Bash/Shell. By doing this, I cannot use PlistBuddy's "Copy" function. I must copy each individual entry over with all of it's elements, since you cannot add/set dictionaries, but must interact with PlistBuddy via "Entries".

What I am trying to do is take Plist File A and store its Titles/Values Arrays for a "PSMultiValueSpecifier" element. I am able to grab the elements in the arrays and print them to the screen, but when I go to add them into the destination Plist file B, the arrays are still empty.

Code: (Code to Grab the Entry for Adding)

```
# Configure the Entry
${PLISTBUDDY} -c "Add PreferenceSpecifiers:$DEST_INDEX dict" ${DEST_PLIST}
${PLISTBUDDY} -c "Add PreferenceSpecifiers:$DEST_INDEX:Type string 'PSMultiValueSpecifier'" ${DEST_PLIST}

# Retrieve the Additional Field Value
preferenceTitle=`$PLISTBUDDY -c "Print PreferenceSpecifiers:$SOURCE_INDEX:Title" $SOURCE_PLIST 2>&1`
preferenceKey=`$PLISTBUDDY -c "Print PreferenceSpecifiers:$SOURCE_INDEX:Key" $SOURCE_PLIST 2>&1`
preferenceDefaultValue=`$PLISTBUDDY -c "Print PreferenceSpecifiers:$SOURCE_INDEX:DefaultValue" $SOURCE_PLIST 2>&1`
preferenceValues=`$PLISTBUDDY -c "Print PreferenceSpecifiers:$SOURCE_INDEX:Values" $SOURCE_PLIST 2>&1`
preferenceTitles=`$PLISTBUDDY -c "Print PreferenceSpecifiers:$SOURCE_INDEX:Titles" $SOURCE_PLIST 2>&1`
```

Code to Add the new Entry:

```
# Set the Additional Field Values
${PLISTBUDDY} -c "Add PreferenceSpecifiers:$DEST_INDEX:Title string $preferenceTitle" ${DEST_PLIST}
${PLISTBUDDY} -c "Add PreferenceSpecifiers:$DEST_INDEX:Key string $preferenceKey" ${DEST_PLIST}
${PLISTBUDDY} -c "Add PreferenceSpecifiers:$DEST_INDEX:DefaultValue integer $preferenceDefaultValue" ${DEST_PLIST}
####BORKEN####
${PLISTBUDDY} -c "Add PreferenceSpecifiers:$DEST_INDEX:Values array $preferenceValues" ${DEST_PLIST}
${PLISTBUDDY} -c "Add PreferenceSpecifiers:$DEST_INDEX:Titles array $preferenceTitles" ${DEST_PLIST}
####BORKEN####
```

Here is a snippet of Code that produces the below data:

```
echo "#########"
echo "[$THIS] adding $preference: $preferenceDict"
echo "#########"
echo "Source: "`$PLISTBUDDY -c "Print PreferenceSpecifiers:$SOURCE_INDEX:Values" $SOURCE_PLIST`
echo "Source: "`$PLISTBUDDY -c "Print PreferenceSpecifiers:$SOURCE_INDEX:Titles" $SOURCE_PLIST`
echo "#########"
echo "Destination: "`$PLISTBUDDY -c "Print PreferenceSpecifiers:$DEST_INDEX:Values" $DEST_PLIST`
echo "Destination: "`$PLISTBUDDY -c "Print PreferenceSpecifiers:$DEST_INDEX:Titles" $DEST_PLIST`
echo "#########"
```

Here is the data provided proving that the proper fields are being transported

```
#########
[addDebugSettingsMenu.bash] adding : Dict {
    Titles = Array {
        Meters
        Feet
    }
    DefaultValue = 1
    Values = Array {
        1
        2
    }
    Key = UserPreferences_UnitsKey
    Type = PSMultiValueSpecifier
    Title = Units
}
#########
Source: Array {     1     2 }
Source: Array {     Meters     Feet }
#########
Destination: Array { }
Destination: Array { }
#########
```

Please help if you have any knowledge regarding undocumented features of PlistBuddy. The MAN pages are super slim and examples are far and between.

I would like to thank you for reading this and for lending your brains to help me solve this major pain in my neck.

Comment: There may be a better way to do this, but I have solved this problem by counting the elements in the source array and then copying them over individually.
    
    ${PLISTBUDDY} -c "Add PreferenceSpecifiers:$DEST_INDEX:Titles array" ${DEST_PLIST}

    ${PLISTBUDDY} -c "Add PreferenceSpecifiers:$DEST_INDEX:Titles:0 string 'TITLE_1'" ${DEST_PLIST}
    ${PLISTBUDDY} -c "Add PreferenceSpecifiers:$DEST_INDEX:Titles:1 string 'TITLE_2'" ${DEST_PLIST}
    etc...

I cannot post this as an answer until 8 hours or 10 reputation, so I will comment it for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a better way to do this, but I have solved this problem by counting the elements in the source array and then copying them over individually.

```
${PLISTBUDDY} -c "Add PreferenceSpecifiers:$DEST_INDEX:Titles array" ${DEST_PLIST}    
${PLISTBUDDY} -c "Add PreferenceSpecifiers:$DEST_INDEX:Titles:0 string 'TITLE_1'" 
${DEST_PLIST} ${PLISTBUDDY} -c "Add PreferenceSpecifiers:$DEST_INDEX:Titles:1 string 'TITLE_2'" ${DEST_PLIST} 
etc...
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [import command](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/PlistBuddy.8.html) in PlistBuddy? It sounds related, but adds the whole target file under the `entry`.

Comment: Yeah, I looked over the import command. It seems to overwrite the Target Entry. What I needed was to append/modify the Target Entry. Essentially what I did was inject the contents of one plist into a subset of the contents of another plist to create a hybrid plist file. This is all done by compile-time build scripts for enhanced debugging settings, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It may fix your problem but it is not the right way to implement in larger merging scripts. Check my ans below.

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -x -c "Print PreferenceSpecifiers" ${FROM_PLIST} > ${TO_PLIST}
```

Answer (score 0):

For something simple like an array of strings, here is code that will combine an arbitrary number of arrays. This example uses the UIAppFonts array common in iOS Info plists.

```
TMP_NAME=`basename $0`
TMP_DIR=`mktemp -d ${PROJECT_TEMP_DIR}/${TMP_NAME}.XXXXXX` || exit 1
FONTS_PLIST="${TMP_DIR}/Fonts.plist"

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add UIAppFonts array" "${FONTS_PLIST}"

# Iterate through each array, adding to the array entry in the temporary plist
index=0
for arg; do
  status=0
  inner_index=0
  while [ ${status} -eq 0 ]; do
    set +e
    # No easy way to get array length, so keep going until we go out of bounds
    entry=`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print UIAppFonts:${inner_index}" "${arg}" 2> /dev/null`
    status=${?}
    set -e
    if [ ${status} -eq 0 ]; then
      /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add UIAppFonts:${index} string ${entry}" "${FONTS_PLIST}"
      index=`expr ${index} + 1`
      inner_index=`expr ${inner_index} + 1`
    fi
  done
done
```