# How to write array of dictionaries to plist using shell script , plistbuddy or any command?

Tags: iphone, ios, shell, command-line

I have fetched multiple dictionaries from multiple plist. after i saved them in an object say array . now i have to merge or write this array to new plist. Is der any command to do this ? i have tried alot and unable to write .

```
target_directory="$(pwd)"/OnePlist/
mkdir $target_directory

find . -name 'feature-manifest.plist' |
{
while read line; do
cp -- "$line" $target_directory ;

#/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy

array+=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print :ModulePlugin:" $line)

echo "echo value: $array"


done

echo "Total files in array : $array"

echo "Total files in array : ${#array[*]}"
```

From above script i am writing ModulePlugin Dict to array from multiple plist's in different folders, i wanna write this array to new plist . Is der any command to do this ?

```
Out put : Total files in array : Dict {
    StoreLocator = Dict {
        Status = Active
        IconText = Store Locator
        InfoPage = StoreLocatorInfo.html
        id = 6
        Priority = 6
        StoryBoard = StoreLocator
        RootViewController = StoreLocatorViewController
        Icon = Images.bundle/HomeScreenIcons/store_locater.png
    }
}Dict {
    Scanner = Dict {
        Status = Active
        IconText = Scanner
        InfoPage = ScannerInfo.html
        id = 6
        Priority = 6
        StoryBoard = Scanner
        RootViewController = ScannerViewController
        Icon = /HomeScreenIcons/multi_scan@2x.png
    }
}Dict {
    Coupons = Dict {
        Status = Active
        IconText = Coupons
        InfoPage = 
        id = 4
        Priority = 4
        StoryBoard = Coupons
        RootViewController = CouponsViewController
        Icon = /HomeScreenIcons/coupons@2x.png
    }
}Dict {
    StoreLocator = Dict {
        Status = Active
        IconText = Store Locator
        InfoPage = StoreLocatorInfo.html
        id = 6
        Priority = 6
        StoryBoard = StoreLocator
        RootViewController = StoreLocatorViewController
        Icon = Images.bundle/HomeScreenIcons/store_locater.png
    }
}
```

Above object which is having multiple dictionaries . i have to write dem into new plist.

Comment: Do you want to do it from inside your code or through shell script only?

Comment: i need it through shell script coz i have to place it in run script of xcode .

Comment: Check this stack overflow [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573017/how-can-i-add-an-array-to-a-plist-using-plistbuddy/18074038#18074038